# Is copy concurrency safe in golang?

Tags: go, concurrency, data-race

In some circumstance, i would copy some content to different piece of the slice. 
Like this

```
a := make([]int, 10)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    b := []int{i}
    go func(i int) {
        copy(a[i:i+1], b)
    }(i)
}
time.Sleep(time.Second)
fmt.Println(a)
```

It leads `DATA RACE`. But it always behave right in product environment.

So my question is:

1. Any data race cloud be undefined behavior?
2. Can i always get right result in such a practice?

Comment: No. Nothing is concurrency safe unless explicitly stated (e.g. channel ops in the Memeory Model) and data races **must** be avoided: A program with a data race is wrong and may produce wrong results at any time.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the data race, which will have undefined results, synchronize. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    a := make([]int, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        b := []int{i}
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            copy(a[i:i+1], b)
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rYCBMV7wuNn

Output:

```
$ go run -race norace.go
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
$
```

---

> [Package sync](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/)
>
> ```
> import "sync"
> ```
>
> [type WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)
>
> A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish. The main
>   goroutine calls Add to set the number of goroutines to wait for. Then
>   each of the goroutines runs and calls Done when finished. At the same
>   time, Wait can be used to block until all goroutines have finished.
>
> A WaitGroup must not be copied after first use.
>
> ```
> type WaitGroup struct {
>         // contains filtered or unexported fields
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trapped in some misunderstanding, in my mind, doing multi `copy`  concurrently cause `data race`. I got it from your answer.